# How to cancel email in delivering_email hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am implementing a email message queue.
I use interceptor.

```
class MyInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(mail)
    Email.queue(mail)
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MyInterceptor)
```

But this code sends email in a normal way.
How do I stop the email from being sent?
I will manually send emails from the queue.

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 9):

Set `Mail::Message#perform_deliveries` to `false`:

```
class NeverDeliverInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.perform_deliveries = false
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(NeverDeliverInterceptor)
```

[See API doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message#perform_deliveries-instance_method) for source & other usage.

Comment: just a heads up, this does work for `deliver!`, only for 'deliver`

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. I just set delivery_method to :test.

Comment: The syntax is: `message.delivery_method :test`

Comment: Beware in a production environment this may take up resources as the TestMailer's deliveries array grows with each message that has the `test` delivery method.

Answer (score 1):

it would probably be better to simply set delivery_method to a custom delivery agent class instead (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html ).